# CRM 2015 unsupported line of code - HTML Resource

Tags: html, dynamics-crm-2015

I just did an upgrade from CRM 2011 to CRM 2015. I was just wondering if the below line of code is supported in CRM 2015. This piece of code is in a HTML resource:

```
document.getElementById('crmGrid').parentElement.innerHTML = document.frames['grid'].document.getElementById('crmGrid').parentElement.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

If that code is running against your own web resource's html, then it is valid and supported.  However, that particular code looks a lot like it might be accessing a grid on the parent CRM form, which is unsupported.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But is there any way I can simplify the code or an alternative code you can think of?

Comment: Without seeing all of the code or knowing what your web resource is trying to do, no. Upgrading a 2011 unsupported feature to a 2015 unsupported feature is probably going to require a sizable overhaul in design due to the vast differences between 2011 and 2015 UIs.